# Different output from selenium driver.page_source and selenium xpaths

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting a different source code when getting it from driver.page_source. I think that for some reason javascript is not loading even though I implicit and explicit wait time wait for it to properly load. The page itself is 'https://www.zingat.com/en/kemer-country-de-satilik-mustakil-4-katli-villa-3902364i' in case if it is relevant.

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("headless")
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    desired_capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities, options = options)

    current_url = 'https://www.zingat.com/en/kemer-country-de-satilik-mustakil-4-katli-villa-3902364i'
    driver.get(current_url)
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    selenium_response_text = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(selenium_response_text, 'html.parser')
    with open('file.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(str(soup))
```

However I can get values the very values that do not seem to load using selenium's xpath.

```
    features_list_names = features_list.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='col-md- 
    6']/strong")
    features_list_data = features_list.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='col-md-6']/span")
    feature_dict = {}

    for feature_name, feature_data in zip(features_list_names, features_list_data):
        feature_dict[feature_name.text] = feature_data.text
```

Can someone please explain to me what is wrong or ideally tell me how to get source code correctly in file? Thanks a lot beforehand.

Comment: Try removing headless so you can see what's happening. It's probably blocking you for being a bot.

Comment: I believe it is not that because the page is loading in headless. also I can still get output through xpaths. Thanks for suggestion though.